# How many ways to distribute 151 candies into 4 bowls?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can we distribute 151 candies to 4 bowls in such a way that the first bowl gets at least 35, the second gets at least 36, the third gets at least 37, and the fourth gets at least 42? It is assumed that the candies are distinguishable and non-identical.
I tried to distribute all 151 candies while still maintaining the required number in each bowl.

Here is my attempt at solving the problem:

$${151 \choose 36}{115 \choose 36}{79 \choose 37}{42 \choose 42}+{151 \choose 35}{116 \choose 37}{79 \choose 37}{42 \choose 42}+{151 \choose 35}{116 \choose 36}{80 \choose 38}{42 \choose 42}+{151 \choose 35}{116 \choose 36}{80\choose 37}{43 \choose 43}$$

Did I go about this the right way or is there an easier way to solve it?

Comment: Are all the candies identical?

Comment: They're not identical to each other. I'll edit to add that, thank you.

Comment: If they were identical, you could do some cool trick. As you're saying they are distinct, I don't know any better way other than this case exhaustive process.

Comment: At least I know I'm on the right track, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The "reserved places" are $150$ candies in total. So there is indeed only one free place, which can be exactly one of the bowls. As the bowls and the candies are all distinct, your solution seems to me the easiest way to do it.